# Qt предупреждения

Tags: c++, qt

Вроде после первичного использования setRootIndex на директорию у QAbstractItemView для модели QFileSystemModel в терминал сыпятся ошибки:

> Case insensitive sorting unsupported in the posix collation implementation
>   Numeric mode unsupported in the posix collationimplementation

Некоторое время не пользовался qt, раньше такого не было, проблема не гуглится, в режиме дебага предупреждения не отображаются, что не так?

Comment: поставьте точку останова в `QCollatorPrivate::init` и посмотрите по стеку

Comment: И как мне в скомпилированной библиотеке точку остановки поставить?

Comment: да прямо исходник открыть и поставить, вот у меня в винде он лежит по адресу `qtbase\src\corelib\tools\qcollator_posix.cpp`, я так часто ищу ошибки, сначала ищешь текст сообщения в исходниках, потом точка останова